# What does txqueuelen 0 mean

Tags: centos, network-interface

I understand that general guidance is txqueuelen should be set to lower value for high latency network; and higher value for servers. I am not clear on significance of 0. Does it mean there is no buffer or does it mean unlimited?

Comment: Maybe this article will help https://www.pc-freak.net/blog/why-and-how-to-increase-and-decrease-txqueuelen-transmit-queue-lenght-in-gnu-linux/